# Subset a matrix according to a columns vector

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix, H. I want to select a value from each row, choosing the column from vector P.

```
H = matrix(data=runif(6),ncol=2)
P = c(2,1,2)
```

The output I am after is a vector containing

```
c(H[1,P[1]],H[2,P[2]],H[3,P[3]])
```

I'm working with larger data, so a generic way of doing this would be good.

This works `diag(H[,P])`, but: a) I don't understand why `H[,P]` returns a square matrix, and b) I would rather not use an extra function (in this case `diag`).

My apologies if this has been asked before.

Comment: `diag(H[,P])` works because it adds columns up to the length of P before calling `diag` That would be less efficient on large matrices.  David's answer below is a very good one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
H[cbind(seq_len(nrow(H)), P)]
## [1] 0.6733731 0.7396847 0.5953580
```

Here we are indexing by consecutive rows and columns indicated in `P`

---

Regarding your question, so the reason `H[, P]` returns a matrix is because you are telling R:

> select all rows in columns: 2, 1, 2 from matrix "H"

thus the result that you are getting is a matrix with identical first and third columns.

Comment: Thanks for this. A simple speed test shows that this approach is faster than diag(H[,P])

Comment: `1:dim(H)[2]` was about twice as fast as `seq_len(nrow(H))`

Comment: For what size of data set?

Comment: Try this: `rm(list= ls() )`

`H = array(data=0, dim=c(10e3,10e3))`
`system.time( for(loop in 1:10e4) 1:dim(H)[2])`
`system.time( for(loop in 1:10e4) seq_len(nrow(H)))`

`H = array(data=0, dim=c(10e1,10e1))`
`system.time( for(loop in 1:10e6) 1:dim(H)[2])`
`system.time( for(loop in 1:10e6) seq_len(nrow(H)))`

Answer (score 0):

> This works, but: a) I don't understand why H[,P] returns a square
>   matrix,

H[,P] returns a square matrix, because P is a vector of length = 3.  Here you are basically saying that you want the matrix returned with the columns 2, 1, and 2 again.

If you want a single value, then you need to pass it a row as well.  You could pass it a random number or something if you want it to randomly choose a row or give it a specific row as well.  For example, row 1:

```
H[1,P]
```

or random (but same across the matrix) row:

```
H[floor(runif(1, 1, dim(H)[1])),P]
```

Comment: thanks for this. I tried h[1:3,P] hoping this would give me the desired result but it didn't work.